# voip client using h.323 in java

Tags: java, voip, h.323

i am trying to write a voip client using h.323 in java and i was wondering if someone could point me as to which api is available in java and if there is any tutorial available for it.anything relevant would be really appreciated. thanx

Comment: I would suggest looking into SIP instead, if you can.

Comment: i am trying to write a client for both sip and h.323, am done with sip am now trying h.323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have many options for H.323 in Java. The best is probably [OPAL](http://www.opalvoip.org/). It includes a Java wrapper to use the C++ class libraries that allow you to implement a Java H.323 client.

IBM used to have a native Java H.323 stack, but I'm not sure if that is maintained anymore.

Comment: thanks for the reply is there any tutorial available for using the java wrapper for opal